# Performance Implications of Reusing DOMDocument Or Creating a New One

Tags: php, performance, dom

Let's say you have a page that has multiple ( 12 ) invocations of this innerHTML function:

```
<?php
function innerHTML($node){
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  foreach ($node->childNodes as $child)
    $doc->appendChild($doc->importNode($child, true));

  return $doc->saveHTML();
}
```

This would result in 12 DOMDocuments being made. Would it be worth it to save a reference to 1 DOMDocument and constantly clean it out per usage? If so, what would be the most efficient method of cleaning it?

Comment: I'd be tempted to try both approaches. (Why estimate what you can measure, after all.)

Comment: I imagine the current way is the best, I'd stick with it :)

Comment: I can setup a simple test but to me at least, this seems like something lots of people have done/worked on.. I suppose I'll stick with just leaving it as is until I hit performance issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any performance issues; `DOMDocument` isn't parsing any XML upon creation.  The most processing intensive operation in the whole thing I think is `saveHTML()`, so you wouldn't save anything by using the same `DOMDocument`.

Destroying the object and creating a new one is likely more efficient than keeping a global variable and emptying it upon every use.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create a [DomDocumentFragment](https://www.php.net/domdocumentfragment)?

```
function innerHTML($node){
    $fragment = $node->ownerDocument->createDocumentFragment();
    foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {
        $fragment->appendChild($child);
    }
    return $node->ownerDocument->saveXml($fragment);
}
```

It has better semantic meaning IMHO, and also saves you from having to import the nodes into a new document (Which likely will be expensive depending on the number of children the node has).

As far as performance levels are concerned, each call took about 0.00005 seconds independent of which function was used (they were with a margin of error from each other)(based on a quick test).  So don't worry too much about it, but also don't do it more than necessary...